# How to Bind SearchBar's TextChanged Trigger to Command using EventToCommand Behavior in Xamarin.Forms using Prism?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I am trying to wire-up the SearchBar control to fire a search/filter on the TextChanged Event/Trigger and not just when the Searchbar is pressed. I am using Prism & MVVM in Xamarin and would prefer to do this with commanding.

This is the code snippet for my Search:

```
  <SearchBar Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="40"   x:Name="CampaignSearchBar"
                       Placeholder="Search for" Text="{Binding SearchTerms}"
                       TextChanged=""
                       SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand }" />
```

Again, I want to bind the TextChanged Event/Trigger to a Command in my ViewModel and not a Event in a page using the Prism Library. I think there is an 'EventToCommandBehavior' class in Prism that can achieve this, however, I am not able to find documentation so far.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a control that does not have a Bindable Command property for the event you need, you can add Prism's `EventToCommandBehavior` to hook into the event you need with a Command from your ViewModel. You can find all of the documentation you need on how to use it in [Prism's docs](http://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/EventToCommandBehavior.html)

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to find these docs in a Google search and nothing came up. I was literally looking at the Github Repo's Getting Started page to find links to the documentation. I will be checking it out

Comment: The docs location did change, but the reference to the docs from the ReadMe on GitHub was also updated to reflect the new link. Glad this is what you needed